# How to get mapViewDidFailLoadingMap(_:withError) called when mapType is set to satelliteFlyover?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

I'm using a MapView and want to display a static image when the map could not be loaded because the device is offline (or tiles could not be loaded for any other reason).

Actually this works when using the `MKMapViewDelegate` and implementing `mapViewDidFailLoadingMap(_:withError)`.

In my case the `MKMapType` is `.satelliteFlyover` and this somehow prevents the delegate method to be called. It works with `.satellite` for example.

I've tested this both in Simulator and on device by turning off any internet connection. An error is printed to the console

> [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 34.21.6 t:4 kt:0 type: 4, -1009:
> NSURLErrorDomain Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The
> Internet connection appears to be offline."
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be
> offline. But nothing else happens.

Am I doing something wrong? If not: how can I achieve my goal to detect the error correctly? (I'd prefer not to make an URL request or use connectivity detection)

Here is my sample implementation using SwiftUI and a `MKMapView` wrapped as `UIViewRepresentable`. Just turn off any internet connection before you run it.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RepresentableMapView()
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct RepresentableMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.mapType = .satelliteFlyover
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: RepresentableMapView

        init(_ parent: RepresentableMapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView, fullyRendered: Bool) {
            print("mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap")
        }

        func mapViewDidFailLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView, withError error: Error) {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using the right tags.

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks for your advice. Which ones would you suggest?